# When to use mutableCopy for NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm watching an old WWDC video and in their splitViewController example, they do this in the delegate methods for the splitViewController:

```
NSMutableArray *toolBarItems = [[toolbar items] mutableCopy];
[toolbarItems removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[toolbar setItems: toolbarItems animated YES];
[toolbarItems release];
```

Is there a general good practice in making a mutableCopy like this for your data in certain methods?  I haven't seen this before and as a new programmer, do not know when or why I would/should use a copy of something instead of the original.  I guess I can see it in something like a list where it is already ordered a certain way, and maybe I would make a copy of it to reorder it in a different way.  But I do not know if that's their reasoning here, and if there are OTHER best practices to do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you've provided, the array provided by [toolbar items] is immutable. If you want to change it, you have to make a mutable version of it, modify *that* instead, and then pass the modified copy back to toolbar, via its setItems:animated: method. The modification in this case is removing the first toolbar item in the array, but to reiterate, you can't modify an immutable array.

Comment: If we want to modify immutable copy then we can also create     [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:] . Then what it make a difference with mutableCopy ?

Comment: @MuraliMohan -mutableCopy provides a copy that is not autoreleased. +[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:] provides a copy that is placed in the autorelease pool; i.e., autoreleased.

Comment: Ok then i will use this [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:].I think it is not autoreleased. My strong question is => instead of going copy we can create new object with existing data and use that as copied object ?

Answer (score 4):

Mutable means change-able.  So, if you need to change the array, you need to obtain a mutable version of it.  `NSArray` implies `NS(Immutable)Array` meaning you can't change it's data.

Comment: If we want to modify immutable copy then we can also create     [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:] . Then what it make a difference with mutableCopy ?